Select subset of columns to maximize number of rows with ones more than zeros
Consider a matrix with m < 10000 rows and n < 1000 columns containing ones and zeros. I need to select k <= n columns so that the number of rows containing more ones than zeros is maximal (k is fixed).
Is there an algorithm for this problem (approximation algorithm will also be ok)?
Example for matrix
1 2 3 4 5 (column numbers)
=========
0 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 0
1 0 0 1 1
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0

For k = 1 the result is column 4 (it gives 4 rows with ones more than zeros)
For k = 2 the result is column 4 and one of (1, 2, 3, 5), they give 2 rows with 1-majority
For k = 3 the result is (1, 2, 4), they give 5 rows with 1-majority.
For k = 4 there are several results (2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 3, 4, 5) with 2 rows of 1-majority.
For k = 5 the only result is (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) with 3 rows of 1-majority.

So you expect as return a list of  column numbers? Do you have a non-trivial example of input and expected output for it?

Added an example. Yes, ideally the result is k column indexes, but the maximal number of rows with 1-majority is also would be ok.

First, let's implement a function that gets the matrix and a column configuration and detects whether the criteria stands:
function moreOnes(matrix, columns) {
    let ones = 0;
    let zeros = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (columns[j]) {
                matrix[i][j] ? ones++ : zeros++;
            }
        }
    }
    return ones > zeros;
}

Then you generate all possible column combinations, that is, columns is an array of true and false values and you loop all possible combinations and find what the result of moreOnes is. If it's true, then see how many columns values were true and store the best you've got so far and whenever you find a better combination, override it. It's best to initialize all columns to be true, and see whether the criteria stands. If so, then you can stop the algorithm, for no better result can possibly found.
If not, then try all combinations where only one column is false and see whether any of them fulfills the criteria. If so, the algorithm stops. If not, then try all combinations where only two columns are false and operate similarly.
With this approach the first time your criteria is fulfilled can stop the algorithm, because it does not matter whether another similarly good combination could be found later on.

The following is an integer-linear programming (ILP) formulation of the problem. I'm skeptical, however, if any ILP software package would be able to compute an optimal solution in a reasonable period of time for a problem with as many rows and columns as stipulated in the question.
We are given:

aij : element in row i, column j, equal to 0 or 1, for all i and j
k : number of columns to select

It is convenient to compute:

u = k/2 + 1 if k is even
u = (k+1)/2 if k is odd

Two sets of variables are needed:

cj : equals 1 if column j is selected; else equals 0, for all j
ri : equals 1 if row i has more 1's than 0's in the columns for which cj = 1; else equals zero

The formulation is
max Σiri
subject to:
Σjaijcj >= riu for all i
Σjcj = k
All variables equal 0 or 1
